# Write custom LateXML rule for Latex package ledmac

Tags: latexml

I want to convert a **Latex** file to **XML** using **LateXML** (version 0.8.2).
As LateXML does not (yet) have conversion rules for the package **ledmac**, I tried to
write them myself, but so far I am failing.

A typical usecase of ledmac would be something like

```
\edtext{some text}{\lemma{text}\Afootnote{some explanation}}
```

I would like to get as a result

```
<edtext>
    some text
</edtext> 
<lemma>
    text
</lemma>
<Afootnote>
    some explanation
</Afootnote>
```

The file test1.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ledmac}

\begin{document}
    \section{First Section}
        Et et possimus non delectus et id dolor fugiat. Nemo aperiam in vitae atque. 
        Qui \edtext{pariatur ut fuga}{\lemma{fuga} \Afootnote{quaerat ratione dolorem ex dicta}}. 
        Sapiente hic est nobis eum. Rerum odit consectetur possimus et quaerat aut veritatis quae.
\end{document}
```

My attempt so far has been to write a file ledmac.sty.ltxml in the same directory as test1.tex.
It has the following content:

```
package LaTeXML::Package::Pool;
use strict;
use LaTeXML::Package;
use warnings;

#RegisterNamespace('scr'=>"http://bla.com/scr");

DefConstructor('\edtext{}', "<edtext>#1</edtext>");
DefConstructor('\lemma{}', "<lemma>#1</lemma>");
DefConstructor('\Afootnote{}',"<Afootnote>#1</Afootnote>");

Tag('edtext', autoClose=>1);
Tag('lemma', autoClose=>1);
Tag('Afootnote', autoClose=>1);
1;
```

However, this results in six errors of the form

```
Error:malformed:edtext <edtext> isn't allowed here
at /media/sf_Dokumente/Leibniz/LeibnizFiles/LateXML-Leibniz/test1.tex; line 6 col 3
Currently in XMLDocument[54493616]<ltx:document _box="LaTeXML::Core::Whatsit=HASH(0x..." _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b..." xmlns="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML">...<ltx:section _box="LaTeXML::Core::Whatsit=HASH(0x..." _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b..." refnum="1" xml:id="S1" _ID_counter_p_="1">...<ltx:para _box="LaTeXML::Core::Box=ARRAY(0x344f300)" _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b..." xml:id="S1.p1">...<ltx:p _box="LaTeXML::Core::Box=ARRAY(0x344f300)" _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b...">...
In Core::Document[@0x34474b8] at /media/sf_Dokumente/Leibniz/LeibnizFiles/LateXML-Leibniz/test1.tex; line 6 col 3
 <= Core::Definition::Constructor[\edtext... <= Whatsit[\edtext,Core::List[Box[p],Box... <= Core::Document[@0x34474b8] <= ...

Error:malformed:edtext Attempt to close </edtext>, which isn't open
at /media/sf_Dokumente/Leibniz/LeibnizFiles/LateXML-Leibniz/test1.tex; line 6 col 3
Currently in XMLDocument[54493616]<ltx:document _box="LaTeXML::Core::Whatsit=HASH(0x..." _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b..." xmlns="http://dlmf.nist.gov/LaTeXML">...<ltx:section _box="LaTeXML::Core::Whatsit=HASH(0x..." _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b..." refnum="1" xml:id="S1" _ID_counter_p_="1">...<ltx:para _box="LaTeXML::Core::Box=ARRAY(0x344f300)" _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b..." xml:id="S1.p1">...<ltx:p _box="LaTeXML::Core::Box=ARRAY(0x344f300)" _font="Font[serif,medium,upright,10,b...">...
In Core::Document[@0x34474b8] at /media/sf_Dokumente/Leibniz/LeibnizFiles/LateXML-Leibniz/test1.tex; line 6 col 3
 <= Core::Definition::Constructor[\edtext... <= Whatsit[\edtext,Core::List[Box[p],Box... <= Core::Document[@0x34474b8] <= ...
```

These errors occur for each of the commands I try to convert.

If someone with LateXML expertise could give me a hint, how to proceed from here, I would be really grateful!

**EDIT**: After posting my question in the LateXML mailing list, I was told that a RelaxNG scheme has to be provided to LateXML. So this seems to be the reason for the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

After consulting the LateXML mailing list, the developer gave me the hint that I need to specify a RelaxNG scheme, which basically specifies the structure of the resulting output file.